# Exponentiation of the Euclidean algebra $\text{e}(n)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know that the Euclidean group $E(n)$ is isomorphic to the set of real matrices of the form
$$
E=\begin{bmatrix}
A &a\\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A\in O(n)$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. It's also clear that it's necessary for matrices in the Lie algebra $\text{e}(n)$ to be of the form
$$
e=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega &v\\
0 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\omega \in \text{o}(n)$ and $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then what is the exponentiation of $e$, i.e., what is $\exp(et)$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$
e=\begin{bmatrix}
\omega &v\\
0 &0
\end{bmatrix} ~,
$$
prove 
$$
t^n e^n=\begin{bmatrix}
t^n \omega^n  &t^n \omega^{n-1}v\\
0 &0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the formal expansion of the exponential sums to 
$$
E=\exp (te) =     \begin{bmatrix}
\exp (t\omega) & \frac{1}{\omega} ~(\exp (t\omega) - 1\!\!  1 )~ v \\
0 &1
\end{bmatrix} ~.
$$
Of course, no actual inverse of *ω* is required to exist, since the formal expansion of the numerator of the matrix acting on *v* is linear in *ω*.